# Call to a member function store() on null on Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm new to Livewire and I faced this problem `Call to a member function store() on null` I don't know how to make the store() function not work when I don't send a file! `graduation_certificate` it is nullable.

Database file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_trainees', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('university_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('department_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('major', 150);
        $table->bigInteger('student_number')->nullable();
        $table->float('gpa');
        $table->enum('gpa_type', array('4', '5'));
        $table->enum('training_date', array('firstsemester', 'secondsemester', 'thirdsemester', 'summersemester'))->nullable();
        $table->integer('training_hours')->nullable();
        $table->integer('graduation_year')->nullable();
        $table->enum('academic_degree', array('bachelor', 'diploma'));
        $table->string('graduation_certificate', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('academic_transaction', 200);
        $table->string('cv', 200);
        $table->tinyInteger('is_graduate');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

blade file

```
<x-form.label label="وثيقة التخرج" name="graduation_certificate" />
                <div class="flex">
                    <input type="file" wire:model="graduation_certificate" name="graduation_certificate"
                        id="graduation_certificate"
                        class="px-8 py-12 border-2 border-dashed rounded-md dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800">
                </div>
```

livewire class

```
    public function submit()
{        
    $user_uni = User::create([
        'name' => "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}",
        'type_id' => $this->userType,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($this->password),
        'gender' => $this->gender,
        'mobile' => $this->mobile,
        'is_active' => 1,
    ]);
    UserTrainee::create([
        'user_id' => $user_uni->id,
        'region_id' => $this->region,
        'city_id' => $this->city,
        'university_id' => $this->university,
        'department_id' => $this->department,
        'major' => $this->major,
        'student_number' => $this->studentNumber,
        'gpa' => $this->gpa,
        'gpa_type' => $this->gpa_type,
        'training_date' => $this->training_date,
        'training_hours' => $this->trainingHours,
        'graduation_year' => $this->graduation_year,
        'academic_degree' => $this->academic_degree,
        'graduation_certificate' => $this->graduation_certificate->store('files', 'public'),
        'academic_transaction' => $this->academic_transaction->store('files', 'public'),
        'cv' => $this->cv->store('files', 'public'),
        'is_graduate' => $this->traineeType,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't conditionally store the files, meaning that even if you haven't uploaded something (meaning its `NULL`), you attempt to store it. Just wrap some conditions around it,

```php
// ...
    'graduation_certificate' => $this->graduation_certificate ? $this->graduation_certificate->store('files', 'public') : null,
    'academic_transaction' => $this->academic_transaction ? $this->academic_transaction->store('files', 'public') : null,
    'cv' => $this->cv ? $this->cv->store('files', 'public') : null,
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make variable of cv like you made for graduation_certificate, cv is getting NULL that's why you are facing this error